# What do we mean when we say 'From $p$ and $p\implies q$, infer $q$'?

Tags: computer-science, boolean-algebra, proof-explanation

There's a question: From $p$ and $p\implies q$, infer $q$. In my book, this is solved algebraically like this:

Given *premises*:
$$P1: p$$
$$P2: p\implies q$$
Conclusion to be drawn: $q$
$$\therefore P1 \bullet P2 \implies C$$
$$= [p.(p\implies q)] \implies q$$
$$= [p.(\bar p + q)] \implies q$$
$$=  (p \bullet \bar p + p \bullet q) \implies q$$
$$=  (0 + p \bullet q) \implies q$$
Carrying out conditional elimination again,
$$(\bar{p+q})+q$$
$$=\bar p + \bar q + q$$
$$=\bar p +1$$
$$=1$$
Hence the result is established.

Now my question is what do we mean when we are here trying to draw conclusion $q$? And what does $1$ as the final result signify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The letters $p, q$ stand for propositions. So, for example, take

- $p$: "I study hard"
- $q$: "I get a good grade"

Then your derivation entails

- $p \Rightarrow q$ and $p$: "If I study hard I get a good grade, and I studied hard". Therefore:
- $q$: "I get a good grade."

The calculation as shown reduces 
\begin{align*}
(p \text{ and } p \Rightarrow q) \Rightarrow q
\end{align*}
to $1$, i.e. to true so that above rule always holds.